# Second monitor freezes

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, screen, monitor

I'm facing the following situation:

I have a laptop and a monitor connected to it. At least once a day, when I'm using Steam and do activities like open the friends list or just closing Steam (top left button Steam -> Exit) my monitor gets frezze and only the laptop screen works.

When it happens I close and open the laptop lid to get my monitor working again but sometime it doesn't work and both screens  (monitor and laptop) gets all black and I only see the mouse pointer and I can hear the sound if I have some video/music playing like in this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OaOJx5NWsMyGfaXt7JrAtNMTkvz-zv0P/view?usp=sharing)

When that situation happens I need to restart the laptop and after restart I can see this error in the logs:

```
drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

Sometimes it happens with other softwares but Steam is the software it most happens with. Someone has any ideia on how to deal with it?

These are my specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 64 bits, 16 RAM
- Gnome version: 42.9
- Windows system: X11
- Processor: Intel Core i7
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1650, driver version: 535.129.03

If you need more information please let me know.